# Get the definition of a word

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In Google Sheets
I need to get the definition of a word into its adjacent cell. The public free url I used in the past in VBA was `url = "https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v1/entries/en/" & wordToDefine`. I created a function like `=GetDefinition(C2)`.

I have tried creating an App Script but keep getting errors and am confused how to reference a function's parameters.

Comment: Add the code that you tried and the texual errors that you got. Are you trying to create a custom function (use your Google Apps Script function as a formula)?

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer:

*You can make the call to the API with `UrlFetchApp`.*

#### Code:

You must first create a custom function in the Apps Script editor with the following code:

```
function getDefinition(cell) {
  var url = "https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v1/entries/en/"
  return UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + cell).getContentText();
}
```

Make sure you run this once to authorise the use of `UrlFetchApp`.

Then, in the sheet, say for example the word 'Hello' is in cell `B3`, in `C3` you can put the following formula:

```
=getDefinition(B3)
```

And you will get a response from the API which you can then process as per your needs:

```
"[
    {
        ""word"": ""hello"",
        ""phonetics"": [
            {
                ""text"": ""/həˈloʊ/"",
                ""audio"": ""https://lex-audio.useremarkable.com/mp3/hello_us_1_rr.mp3""
            },
            {
                ""text"": ""/hɛˈloʊ/"",
                ""audio"": ""https://lex-audio.useremarkable.com/mp3/hello_us_2_rr.mp3""
            }
        ],
        ""meaning"": {
            ""exclamation"": [
                {
                    ""definition"": ""Used as a greeting or to begin a phone conversation."",
                    ""example"": ""hello there, Katie!""
                }
            ],
            ""noun"": [
                {
                    ""definition"": ""An utterance of “hello”; a greeting."",
                    ""example"": ""she was getting polite nods and hellos from people"",
                    ""synonyms"": [
                        ""greeting"",
                        ""welcome"",
                        ""salutation"",
                        ""saluting"",
                        ""hailing"",
                        ""address"",
                        ""hello"",
                        ""hallo""
                    ]
                }
            ],
            ""intransitive verb"": [
                {
                    ""definition"": ""Say or shout “hello”; greet someone."",
                    ""example"": ""I pressed the phone button and helloed""
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]"
```

#### References:

- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)